# How to pass Input value to ng change function in ng repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
document.getElementById(productrate).value = data[0].purches_rate;
```

I am getting product rate value form js using above line

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="productrate"  id="productrate{{$index}}"/>
```

But unable to passing that value in below change function

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="finalqty" ng-model="finalqty"   ng-change="change_qty(productrate,finalqty)"/>
```

How can i Input value to ng change function in ng repeat. Is there any solution? please help

Thanks you

Comment: Don't use ng-model without a dot. You should put finalqty in an object like `$scope.form = {finalqty: 0};` and write `ng-model="form.finalqty"`. It's a classic problem with scope.

Comment: Not a problem  with finalqty, problem is i need to pass productrate in  change_qty function

Comment: Can't get what you're doing here... Could you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: kindly refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48946868/unable-to-assign-the-document-getelementbyid-value-to-ng-model-in-ng-repeat?noredirect=1#comment84903653_48946868